# Remove elements from array by name

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'd like to know how to remove `boats` from my array.

```
var obj = [
    { car: 1, boat: 2, plane: 3  },
    { car: 3, boat: 9, plane: 12  }
];


// Desired output
[
   { car: 1, plane: 3 },
   { car: 3, plane: 12 }
];
```

What I tried is to use `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
console.log(obj.filter(el => el (how to get el name) === 'boat'));
```

Comment: You want `obj.map( ({car, boat, plane}) => ({car, plane}) )`. You don't want to filter the array, you want to make different objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create new array and not to modify your existing array:

```
var obj = [
    { car: 1, boat: 2, plane: 3  },
    { car: 3, boat: 9, plane: 12  }
];

var newArr = obj.map(e => ({car: e.car, plane: e.plane}));
// newArr = [{car: 1, plane: 3},{car: 3, plane: 12}]
```

Comment: correct, I don't want to modify my existing array. @sidanmor - how can this scale if there are 50+ properties?

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing elements from an array; instead you want to remove properties from existing objects, which happen to be array elements.

Use the `delete` operator to remove properties from objects. As you're not removing elements from an array you won't need to use `filter` either:

```
for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) {
    delete obj[i]['boat'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete it

```
obj.forEach(function(el){
  delete el.boat;
})
//"[{"car":1,"plane":3},{"car":3,"plane":12}]"
```